# Model application on specific rows of a dataset

Tags: dataframe, model, output, stata

I have never used Stata before, I know how to solve the issue in R, but I must solve this issue in Stata.

I have a dataset (let's call it dataset1), and I want to run a specific model (model1) on the first 4000 rows of observations. The rest 3000 observations will be my test set.

I want to repeat the process for 10 more datasets (variables and Y are exactly the same). In R this example is simple:

```
model1.1<-lm(Y~x1+x2+x3, data=dataset1[1:4000,]
model1.2<-lm(Y~x1+x2+x3, data=dataset2[1:4000,]
model1.3<-lm(Y~x1+x2+x3, data=dataset3[1:4000,]
```

I want that in Stata. I want to store as well the outputs for each of those results (in R for example I can save it `model1.1.summary<-summary(model1.1)`. What lines of code do I need to do that part as well? I am extremely confused. I would run the model in R if it was as efficient as it was in Stata.

So far I have the model running in Stata.

```
meoprobit Y X1 X2 X3|| LVL:
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either append the ten datasets, or loop through each of the ten datasets. I think the latter is easier.

(code is untested as a data example was not provided)

Assuming datasets are named `dataset1` `dataset2` etc.

```
forvalues i = 1/10 { 
    
    * Open dataset
    use "FILEPATH/dataset`i'.dta", clear
    
    * Run model on first 4000 obs
    meoprobit Y X1 X2 X3 in 1/4000 || LVL:
    
    * Store model estimates
    estimates store M`i'
}
```

See `help estimates` for details on what you can do with stored model estimates.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a test; to clarify something: the estimates store M"i", can work for model 1 on that dataset. If I want to run on the same dataset another model, let's say model 2, can I put another separate loop like the one you sent, but at the end it will have: estimates store K"i" ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it would work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it yesterday night, and it seemed that it was working, but for some reason, when using the loop, I get no-observations error. However, when i run the same model outside of the loop it's producing all the results. I am going to try again just in case I was missing something, or I did something to the data.

Comment: I suggest checking that each of your ten datasets have at least 4000 observations and don't contain 100% missing values for any of the variables included in the model.

Comment: They are 7800obs, and in the columns that I have some NAs (but not too many) it runs on the 7800 full dataset. When I put it from the for-loop to run on the 4900 it gives the error.

Comment: Maybe try running the `forvalues` loop without the `in 1/4000`, and see if that works